# what really happen when I assign a value to a variable?

Tags: python, architecture

I have a question in my mind for a while and it looks a little bit silly! I would like to understand what really happen when we assign a value to a variable in a programming language like python (for example a=2). All teacher say 'a' stores in RAM and then the value '2' is assigned to the variable. But how? What happen when I write this code and then push 'Enter' on my computer keyboard(I mean after execute this line of the code)?
This is my guess! the ascii code of 'a' is 97 and the binary representation of 97 is (01100001). and '2' also is (00000010). I think RAM made up billion of transistors stuck together in a matrix shape and the turned off and turned on transistor show '0' and '1'. Is it true? Do we have only billion transistors in RAM memory space and nothing else?
How close is this assumption to reality?

Answer (score 0):

Python is a dynamically typed language.

So, Python doesn't need an explicit variable declaration to reserve memory.

The variable declaration will happen automatically when we assign value to it.

So when you assign value to a variable like in your example: `a =2`

Value 2 will not be directly assigned to the variable 'a'. Instead, an integer object with a value of 2 will be assigned to the variable 'a'.

I believe [this link](http://foobarnbaz.com/2012/07/08/understanding-python-variables/) will benefit you in getting a more clarified idea.

Hopefully, I was able to help.

Comment: Thank you. Python is just a programming language example in my question. What I really want to know is, what happen in random memory access in an computer architectural or hardware point of view.